# Mutating a zipped iterator in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator

How do I zip up an iterator to some type that implements `IntoIterator` and mutate that type inside of a loop like this ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%23%5Bderive(Default%2C%20Debug)%5D%0Astruct%20Data%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20values%3A%20%5Bbool%3B%204%5D%2C%0A%7D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20d%20%3D%20Data%3A%3Adefault()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20d)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(i%2C%20(v%2C%20dv))%20in%20%5Btrue%2C%20false%2C%20false%2C%20true%5D.iter().zip(d.values.iter()).enumerate()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20*v%20!%3D%20*dv%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d.values%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20*v%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20d)%3B%0A%7D%0A)):

```
#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct Data {
    pub values: [bool; 4],
}
fn main() {
    let mut d = Data::default();
    println!("{:?}", d);
    
    for (i, (v, dv)) in [true, false, false, true].iter().zip(d.values.iter()).enumerate() {
        if *v != *dv {
            d.values[i] = *v;
        }
    }
    
    println!("{:?}", d);
}
```

This does not compile with the following error:

```
  Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `d.values[_]` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:11:13
   |
9  |     for (i, (v, dv)) in [true, false, false, true].iter().zip(d.values.iter()).enumerate() {
   |                         ------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                         |                                     |
   |                         |                                     borrow of `d.values[_]` occurs here
   |                         borrow later used here
10 |         if *v != *dv {
11 |             d.values[i] = *v;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `d.values[_]` occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0506`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `iter_mut` to get mutable references instead of shared references. This also means you can omit the `enumerate` call since the index isn't needed any longer.

```rust
    for (dv, v) in d.values.iter_mut().zip([true, false, false, true]) {
        if v != *dv {
            *dv = v;
        }
    }
```

Notes:

- I swapped `d.values` and the array because that allows ommiting the explicit call to `iter` and uses `into_iter` instead which in turn allows to avoid having to dereference `v` inside the loop.
- Your loop is equivalent to `d.values = [true, false, false, true]` I assume that's because this is a minimal example.

Comment: So getting a mutable reference to the objects inside the array is equivalent to the bracket index syntax? 

Also yes in the actual application I have in mind these values would be dynamically changing.